# How to make a montage of different-sized images

Tags: matlab

I'm trying to make a montage of figures in Matlab, each figure comprising a row - I have about 12 rows in total. I tried making the whole thing with subplot but the resolution is limited by the screensize and too low. Then I tried saving each figure as an image, using export_fig, and arranging these with subplot but again the resolution is too low. So then I tried montage, but it expects the images to be the same size and they aren't quite (height varies slightly), and export_fig doesn't seem to have the option to control the crop size. If anybody has any solutions I would be grateful!

Comment: Could you provide any example code of what you currently have, so that we can realize the details of your problem?

Comment: zero pad your images so they're all the same size then `montage`?

Comment: Hi @Yvon, I don't really have code written as such: the figs are exported as follows(inside a loop from 1 to j):  export_fig(sprintf('fig%s', num2str(j+1)),'-png','-m2.5','-nocrop'); then I need to load all the images and make one large image, while preserving the resolution etc. Not sure if that clarifies?

Comment: Hi @nkjt, I wondered about zero padding but wasn't sure how to do that (I'm a bit new to matlab) - if you could elaborate that would be really useful.

Answer (score 0):

This is my suggestion:

First resize your images to the same size.

For example,

```
B = imresize(A, [512 512]);
```

Second you can use montage or you can use [imgdisp](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/22387-imdisp)

Imgdisp gives you more options than montage. You can consider using it..

Comment: Thanks @lakesh, I tried both: imresize seems, as far as I can tell, to just rescale the whole image?  However imdisp (I assume you meant?) works well, except that it creates colored numbers on each of the sub-images but I can probably figure out how to fix that. Thank you for that pointer!

Comment: @Kate imdisp would be better than montage. Secondly, by resizing your size issue will gone. All will be scaled to same size.